# Android: eclipse workspace takes a long time to build?

Tags: android, eclipse

My eclipse workspace has just one android project in it and is set to "build automatically".  Every time I make a change to some code, and save the change, the workspace builds.  Initially this is fine, but at some point the builds start to take about 5 seconds for every change.  At this point, I create a new workspace and import the project, and everything works great for a while (days or weeks), but inevitably it slows down again.  Has anyone else experienced this and/or have a solution?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Get IntelliJ Idea, the free community edition, and forget about these problems ;)

Comment: Currently Helios, but had the same issue in Galleio.

Comment: Maybe some of opened projects in your workspace are unnecessary and 'heavy'. Try to close them

Comment: I just started having this problem over the past week - Using Helios Eclipse. Rather than disabling auto-build, have you had any luck?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try in Eclipse:

Window - > Preferences - > Android -> Build -> Skip packaging and dexing export or launch.(Speeds up automatic builds on file save)

And

UnMark : Project - > Build Automatically

And you can also complete with :

Window - > Preferences - > General -> Workspace - > Linked Resource - Enable linked resource (unmark)  try only if your project not have resources from other project.

For me stoped building slow process after every save.

Comment: And don't forget to enable snapshots

Comment: @GabrielFair its applicable only if you are running on emulator.

Answer (score 3):

Under top menu item Project->Build Automatically
uncheck the option, then you'll have to build project manually before testing, just select Project->Build Project then Run after build completes.

Answer (score 3):

Increasing `Xms` and `Xmx` parameters in `eclipse.ini` worked for me:

Original values:

```
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
```

New values:

```
-Xms256m 
-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you clean your project (menu 'project'-> clean) and does that help?

This might be something that's a part of the slowness, although it doesn't explain why it's quick after a new import, and then slows down: [Android compilation is slow (using Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883635/android-compilation-is-slow-using-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the device from USB & then re-connect.