# How to avoid the "User Operation is Waiting" dialog come out in Eclipse/ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

[image]

As shown in the image, when I'm developing Android applications with auto build, sometimes this dialog will show. Is there any way to avoid this and make it just go through the process in the background?

It does not always show, but when it does, I need to wait for it for 5-10 seconds. That's annoying, especially considering that when the project gets bigger, it will go much slower.

**UPDATED:**
I did some researching:

[Android compilation is slow (using Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883635/android-compilation-is-slow-using-eclipse)

[Android: eclipse workspace takes a long time to build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596445/android-eclipse-workspace-takes-a-long-time-to-build)

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a16202975510de39

http://oae9.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/android-workaround-for-slow-building-workspace-problem-in-eclipse/

http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html

Is it there any easier solution that is not using ANT?
Or any other best ANT script that can be applied easily?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514987/user-operation-is-waiting-for-building-workspace

Comment: Vote for https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=329657 - An active build blocks user task (like save)

Answer (score 2):

How about you just uncheck the "Build Automatically" option.  This doesn't speed the build process, but doesn't do it everytime you save a file.

You will still need to do a build that takes a bit of time - but you will only do it when you really want to compile your project (not everytime you make a change to the code).